# Concatenar dataframes que pueden tener fechas en comun

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe inicial, llamemoslo `df`que luce así:

```
|date        |Colombia   |Peru   |Argentina   |Chile   |Brazil   |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|2020-09-26  |3          |5      |1           |4        |2       |
|2020-09-27  |5          |5      |1           |2        |3       |
|2020-09-28  |3          |1      |2           |6        |5       |
|2020-09-29  |1          |6      |1           |2        |4       |
|2020-09-30  |1          |7      |1           |2        |0       |
```

Y debo concatenarlo con dataframes para cada país, que pueden o no tener fechas en común con dataframes por cada país, llamemos a uno en particular `df2`, que lucen así:

```
|             |Colombia |
------------------------
|datetime     |         |
-------------------------
|2020-10-01   |4        |
|2020-10-02   |2        |
|2020-10-03   |3        |
|2020-10-04   |5        |
|2020-10-05   |1        |
|2020-10-06   |0        |
```

Todos los dataframe están indexados por fechas.

Necesito que, si llegara a existir en los dataframe como `df2` una fecha que ya está en `df`, ponga el valor que ya está en `df` y en otro caso que concatene los dos dataframe y ponga las fechas que están n df2 con su respectivo valor.

Esto fue lo que intenté:

```
dates_ind = numpy.in1d(df2.index, df.index)
    if numpy.any(dates_ind):
        df.loc[df2.index[dates_ind]][df2.columns[0]] = df2.loc[dates_ind].values.flatten()

    else:
        df = pd.concat([df, df2.loc[~dates_ind]], axis=0).drop_duplicates(keep="first")
```

Pero el problema es que pone `NA` en las fechas que no están en el dataframe inicial, `df`, por ejemplo:

```
|date        |Colombia   |Peru   |Argentina   |Chile   |Brazil   |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|2020-09-26  |3          |5      |1           |4        |2       |
|2020-09-27  |5          |5      |1           |2        |3       |
|2020-09-28  |3          |1      |2           |6        |5       |
|2020-09-29  |1          |6      |1           |2        |4       |
|2020-09-30  |1          |7      |1           |2        |0       |
|2020-10-01  |NA         |NA     |NA          |NA       |NA      |
|2020-10-02  |NA         |NA     |NA          |NA       |NA      |
|2020-10-03  |NA         |NA     |NA          |NA       |NA      |
|2020-10-04  |NA         |NA     |NA          |NA       |NA      |
|2020-10-05  |NA         |NA     |NA          |NA       |NA      |
|2020-10-06  |NA         |NA     |NA          |NA       |NA      |
```

Intenté también en esta linea del código

```
df = pd.concat([df, df2.loc[~dates_ind]], axis=0).drop_duplicates(keep="first")
```

Quitar la virgulilla: `~`, pero lo que hizo fue ni siquiera poner las fechas que sí estan en los `df2` y no en `df`:

```
|date        |Colombia   |Peru   |Argentina   |Chile   |Brazil   |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|2020-09-26  |3          |5      |1           |4        |2       |
|2020-09-27  |5          |5      |1           |2        |3       |
|2020-09-28  |3          |1      |2           |6        |5       |
|2020-09-29  |1          |6      |1           |2        |4       |
|2020-09-30  |1          |7      |1           |2        |0       |
```

Y ya no se qué más hacer... ¿Me pueden ayudar?

Comment: podrías colocar un ejemplo de la salida esperada?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la función que buscas es [`combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html).

Ya que vas a utilizar la fecha como clave, debes establecerla como índice en los dos dataframes.

Con el índice correctamente establecido simplemente utiliza combine_first() utilizando como base el dataframe `df2`. Esta función actualiza los valores null de un dataframe con los valores de otro, por lo que los datos no existentes en `df2` se completarán con los de `df`.

```
# He utilizado datetime en el df base por ser el que has puesto en tu pregunta.
out = df2.set_index('datetime').combine_first(df.set_index('date'))
```

En caso de que te quieras quedar sólo con las filas que tengan datos para todos los paises sería tan sencillo como hacer un drop de las filas que tengan algún `nan`

```
out = df2.set_index('datetime').combine_first(df.set_index('date')).dropna(how='any')
```